# Anti alias mode differences?

Tags: .net, vb.net, graphics, system.drawing, antialiasing

Is there a difference between these two Anti Alias modes?

```
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias

e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality
```

I've tested both methods and can't see any difference.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no difference. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9.aspx :

> AntiAlias and HighQuality are equivalent and specify rendering with smoothing applied.

Comment: Interesting to note that their values are different, i.e. `SmoothingMode.AntiAlias != SmoothingMode.HighQuality`.