# Confusion. Difference between SmoothingMode.AntiAlias and SmoothingMode.HighQuality

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z714w2y9(v=vs.110).aspx) page says:

> AntiAlias and HighQuality are equivalent and specify rendering with
>   smoothing applied.

But then why do they both exist if they are equivalent? Does one have any *other* differences other than what we see? I.e. Does one perform better over the other, or is it just a case of one of them being implemented much sooner than the other and therefor is only really there for backwards-compatibility?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Anti alias mode differences?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15926123/anti-alias-mode-differences)

Comment: @PeterKostov Completely different questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've made some researchs, and here's what I've found :

"HighQuality (which is similar to AntiAlias but uses other, slower optimizations that improve the display on LCD screens)"

Comment: Thank you very much @Isuka, I very much appreciate this. Do you happen to have that source? All good if you don't have it though :)

Comment: I've found it in the "Pro ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010" book, page 1144. You can find it online with Google books.